# Autocomplete an Input based on another Input with Percentages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

first of all, please excuse me if I'm missing any info or I'm not being clear, I'm very new at this, still getting the hang of it.

I have the following form:

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Qvsi.png)

**I need the two % input fields to autocomplete so the sum is 100%. If input one is 90%, input 2 should autocomplete to 10% and vice-versa.**

This is the HTML:

```
<!-- Tabla - - - - - - - -->
<div id="distDosFondos" class="table-responsive cambioDist">
    <p>Selecciona fondos y porcentajes a distribuir:</p>
    <!--table-responsive-->
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Fondo</th>
                <th>%</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <!-- Fila Cambio y Distribución de Fondos -->
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="inputForm">
                        <select class="chosen" id="fondos1" name="fondos1">
                            <option value="">Fondo</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="inputForm">
                        <input id="porcentage1" name="porcentage" type="text" class="form-control porcentage porcentaje1">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- //Fila Cambio y Distribución de Fondos -->
            <!-- Fila Cambio y Distribución de Fondos -->
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="inputForm">
                        <select class="chosen" id="fondos2" name="fondos2">
                            <option value="">Fondo</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="porcentage2" name="porcentage" type="text" class="form-control porcentage porcentaje2">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- //Fila Cambio y Distribución de Fondos -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<!-- Tabla - - - - - - - -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways that you could approach this, but this is a pretty simple solution.

First, set up a handler for the `input` event of your two inputs

```
$("[name='porcentage']").on("input", function() {
    ...
});
```

Now, inside of this, you'll be handling changing the other input. First, let's make sure the percentage can't be over 100 and can't be below 0.

```
if($(this).val() > 100)
    $(this).val(100);
else if($(this).val() < 0)
    $(this).val(0);
```

Next, you need to get the other input, the one you want to change.

```
var otherInput = $(this).attr("id") == "porcentage1" ? $("#porcentage2") : $("#porcentage1");
```

Finally, set the other input's value to make the two add up to 100.

```
$(otherInput).val(100 - $(this).val());
```

Full code:

```
$("[name='porcentage']").on("input", function() {
    if($(this).val() > 100)
        $(this).val(100);
    else if($(this).val() < 0)
        $(this).val(0);

    var otherInput = $(this).attr("id") == "porcentage1" ? $("#porcentage2") : $("#porcentage1");
    $(otherInput).val(100 - $(this).val());
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q0bk5sns/3/)

Comment: Two more questions:

1. Does this work on IE8?
2. How can I add the % symbol once the values are set?

Comment: 1. No clue, you'd have to test it, but I wouldn't worry about supporting IE8. 2. You can just concatenate a percent sign whenever you set the value, but this might be confusing to the user. You already have a % above the inputs, so I wouldn't say it's necessary

Comment: Have to validate on IE8, the client asked for it.
Also for the % sign, it's on the design I was given so I have to make it exactly like that >.<

Comment: You can do it like this https://jsfiddle.net/q0bk5sns/4/, but you won't be able to use the `keyup` event. This means that it won't fill in the other input until you click away from the focused one.

Comment: Thanks! It's all up and running now :D

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use the jQuery library:

```
$('#porcentage1, #porcentage2').on('input', function (event) {
        var inputValue = parseInt($(this).val());

        if (inputValue >= 0 && inputValue <= 100) { //ensure number is between 0 and 100
            var otherValue = 100 - inputValue;
            if (this.id === 'porcentage1') { //determines which input element was filled
                $('#porcentage2').val(otherValue);
            } else {
                $('#porcentage1').val(otherValue);
            }
        }
})
```

You may have to use other validations/checks to make sure that the user is actually inputting a number, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery:

```
// attach a bunch of events to both inputs to handle any kind of change
['change', 'keyup', 'paste'].forEach(function(event) {

    // .bind here essentially serves to pass reference of the current updated input, and the other input wich will be updated
    porcentage1.addEventListener(event, onPercentageChange.bind(null, porcentage1, porcentage2));
    porcentage2.addEventListener(event, onPercentageChange.bind(null, porcentage2, porcentage1));
});

function onPercentageChange(updatedInput, otherInput) {

    var updatedValue = parseInt(updatedInput.value) || 0;

    otherInput.value = 100 - updatedValue;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tb7a7joc/

works IE9+